# how to create .property file in specflow framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow, allure

i need to generate allure result .now i am generating allure result in cmd by giving manualy the commands. so i want to automate that.i have created generic fuction for open the cmd and executing a specified command to serve allure result. in hooks i want add this method after run.in this case i need a .property file to store the paths

so i don't know how to .proprty file and its structure. could please explain how to do that? in specflow is there any alternative to do this

Comment: The Allure project has SpecFlow adapter which is also opensource on github under Apache 2.0 so you could start there if you can't use it directly. Beyond that, [this github issue](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/966) tracks documentation for writing custom adapters, including the description you ask for here. That being said. I don't know this framework and just used google and official docs.

Comment: Your implementation of this functionality should include an implementation of the core Allure event and logic for saving information about test events to XML. Language APIs should be implemented once for each programming language. For details, please refer to: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/wiki/Creating-Allure-Adapter